# variable with lt jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my JS looks like

```
var h = 9;
$('#List li:lt('+x')').show();
if (x < listnumber) {
  $('#List li:lt(5)').hide();
}
```

I think I can just cache `$('#List li')` as a var,

```
var $list = $('#List li')
```

But how can I combine it? I tried following format, but doesn't work for me

```
$('#List li')+(':lt(5)')
or $('#List li').is(':lt('+x+')')?
```

Comment: Where are you defining x and listnumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you cache the `$('#List li')` in a var, use `.filter()` on that variable.

For more information on how to use .filter() API function http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
var h = 9;
var $cacheditems = $('#List li');
$cacheditems.filter(':lt(' + h + ')').show();
if (x < listnumber) {
  $cacheditems.filter(':lt(5)').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var h = 9;
var cache = $('#List li');

cache.filter(':lt('+hx+')').show();
if (x < listnumber) {
  cache.filter(':lt(5)').hide();
}
```